# Android - rowIndex is less than 0 when updating RealmList from Activity

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` and is using `RealmResult` as my dataset.

Here's the Adapter code :

```
private RealmList<MessageItem> mDataset;

public ChatRoomAsUserAdapter(Context context, @Nullable RealmList<MessageItem> data) {
    super(data, true);
    this.context = context;
    this.userId = Utilities.getUserInformation(context, SharedPreferencesList.userIDString);
    this.mDataset = data;
}
```

Here's how I find the RealmResult in Activity for chat room initialization :

```
AppController.realm.beginTransaction();
// Getting chat inside the specific room id
ChatRoomWrapper chatFriendRealmResult = AppController.realm.where(ChatRoomWrapper.class)
        .equalTo(ChatRoomWrapperFields.ROOM_ID, roomId).findFirst();
if (chatFriendRealmResult != null){
    chatRoomAsUserAdapter = new ChatRoomAsUserAdapter(this, chatFriendRealmResult.message);
    AppController.realm.commitTransaction();
}
...
```

After the initialization, I make an API call and in the result :

```
chatRoomWrapper.message.deleteAllFromRealm();
chatRoomWrapper.message.addAll(api.res.message_item_list);
Appcontroller.realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(chatRoomWrapper);
```

And I get this error :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex is less than 0.
at io.realm.internal.LinkView.nativeGetTargetRowIndex(Native Method)
at io.realm.internal.LinkView.getTargetRowIndex(LinkView.java:82)
at io.realm.RealmList.get(RealmList.java:452)
```

Does that mean that the content of RV is changed unexpectedly? I am using `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` which should handle that right?

UPDATE :

Here's an example on how I get the data :

`getItem(position).getMsg_date();`

where

```
public class MessageItem extends RealmObject {
    ...
    public String msg_date = "";
}
```

EDIT :

This is how I update the adapter after getting information from server :

```
AppController.realm.beginTransaction();
// Create new ChatFriendWrapper and input the Room ID into it to update
// the Room ID if found
ChatRoomWrapper chatRoomWrapper = AppController.realm.where(ChatRoomWrapper.class)
        .equalTo("room_id", roomId).findFirst();
if (chatRoomWrapper != null) {
    if (output.flag.equals(Constants.flagRefresh)) {
        counter = 0;
        chatRoomWrapper.message.deleteAllFromRealm();
        chatRoomWrapper.message.addAll(output.message_item_list);
        MIApplication.realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(chatRoomWrapper);
        manager.scrollToPosition(0);
    } else if (output.flag.equals(Constants.flagLoad)) {
        chatRoomWrapper.message.addAll(output.message_item_list);
        AppController.realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(chatRoomWrapper);
    }
} else {
    ChatRoomWrapper newChatRoomWrapper = new ChatRoomWrapper();
    newChatRoomWrapper.room_id = roomId;
    newChatRoomWrapper.message.addAll(output.message_item_list);
    AppController.realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newChatRoomWrapper);
    setupChatRoom();
}
AppController.realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: What version of Realm is this?

Comment: The Fabled @EpicPandaForce! It's Realm 3.1.2, I like your name BTW :D

Comment: Sometimes I feel like I should have used this name in more places, but alas :p I like it too, it's well-searchable. Anyhoo, You might want to remove `this.mDataset = data;` and `mDataset` altogether, and use `getData()`/`updateData()` instead.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Haha yeah it's unique, that's why I still remember your name after I came across it somewhere in SO! And btw, I am the same guy in that Realm issues, asking mostly the same thing, hoping some people in SO can help too.. Hm I've tried what you said, but it still reports the same error, anything else I can do?

Comment: In that case I kinda need the next line of the stack trace that specifies where you are calling the `get()` that crashes in your code

Comment: Updated the question! Check it out :D

Comment: You might want to try using `executeTransactionAsync()` and see if that helps.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Sorry, I am a bit overwhelmed with other modules so I haven't checked this module back. I'll update when the said module is being worked on again, prolly in this week! :D

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Hiya there, miss me? Lol. I finally managed to clear things up! The culprit is almost invisible! Hahahhaa. I am going to post the answer here.

Comment: Oops nevermind @EpicPandaForce, I met with the same problem if I were to copyOrUpdate the dataset the adapter is using.

Comment: Nevermind @EpicPandaForce, I found the problem and the solution is actually the same.. Posting the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was the usage of `position` instead of `holder.getAdapterPosition()` to get the item. I used to do this :

`viewholder.message.setText(getItem(position).message);`

now it's

`viewholder.message.setText(getItem(holder.getAdapterPosition()).message);`

And it cleared the error. I suddenly remember when I used to have problems with infinite scrolling in `RecyclerView`, I came across this kind of error too.